# SQL - Search for WHERE clause with no spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am trying to find a performance smart resolution to searching on data that is coming into an application with character spaces removed, but could exist in the DB system in many ways with spaces. I was thinking the following, but it seems to fail:

```
select top 1 * where REPLACE(Mfr, ' ', '') = @Mfr and REPLACE(Model, ' ', '') = @Model
```

Am I doing this completely wrong and is there a better way? It appears to time out only only a DB with 150k records at the moment.

Comment: You can create virtual columns with the replace expressions and then you could create indexes on those virtual columns. Considering you are using equality, the index search should be pretty much instantaneous.

Comment: Amazing, i didn't know you could do that. Do you know of a good clear reference for this concept? I know i can also google it, but to make sure im reading good material and not overly bloated or anything.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/indexes-on-computed-columns?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What happened to the alter Answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the expressions as indexed virtual columns for fast lookup.

1. First you'll need to create the virtual columns:

   ```
   alter table t add clean_mfr as replace(Mfr, ' ', '');

   alter table t add clean_model as replace(Model, ' ', '');
   ```
2. Then you'll index them:

   ```
   create index ix1 on t (clean_mfr, clean_model);
   ```

Now, you can try your query again. Since you are using equality (`=`) in both virtual columns lookups the query should be instantaneous.

Try:

```
select top 1 * 
from t
where REPLACE(Mfr, ' ', '') = @Mfr and REPLACE(Model, ' ', '') = @Model
```

Or:

```
select top 1 * 
from t
where clean_mfr = @Mfr and clean_model = @Model
```

Comment: These are known as "computed columns" in sql server and the syntax is a bit different than the Oracle syntax. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017 But the concept is the same.

Comment: Are you sure this is valid for SQL Server?   I don't see it in the ALTER TABLE documentation.

Comment: Darn it, I thought I was going to learn something new.   I was wondering why he was calling them "virtual" and not "computed"...

Comment: Fixed. I got the wrong docs from Oracle (for some reason) into the wrong local folder. Just tried this syntax and it works.